# Getting last inserted id from SQL itself in Informix

Tags: sql, informix

How can I get the last inserted ID from an SQL statement in Informix. I know about DBINFO but how to get the SQL like "insert into table_name (fields) values (values)" to return the last inserted ID?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  Please do not use abbreviations like 'knw abt'; use full English words.

Answer (score 3):

Which host language?

The information about the value created for a SERIAL column is in the SQLCA (SQL Communications Area).  The information about the value created for a BIGSERIAL column is available via a function call.  The information about the value created for a SERIAL8 column is available via a different function call.  However, the details differ between ESQL/C and ODBC and JDBC and ... If you have both a SERIAL and either a SERIAL8 or BIGSERIAL, you can find both lots of information (but there would be questions about why you have both types in one table).

The question [Informix: how to get an id of the last inserted record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246983/informix-how-to-get-an-id-of-the-last-inserted-record) provides similar information to this (and thanks to [seekerOfKnowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447729/seekerofknowledge) for finding it).

Comment: Hi Jonathan,Thanks for that and sorry about not using full english words. now I am after returning the last inserted serial id from the sql itself..for example,if you have a sql to insert a record to a table and if that table has a serial column how to make it return the last inserted serial id ? an example sql would be useful .Thanks

Comment: My initial question stands — which language?  And SQL is not an answer; SPL might be.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work if you want strictly SQL.

select tabid
   FROM "informix".systables
  where tabname = 'sm_job_cost'
/* 607 */

SELECT DBINFO( 'sqlca.sqlerrd1' ) FROM systables WHERE tabid = 607;
/* 0 */

insert into sm_job_cost (smjc_jb_prodlnk, smjc_prft_ctr) values (1, 2)

SELECT DBINFO( 'sqlca.sqlerrd1' ) FROM systables WHERE tabid = 607;
/* 1 */

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is obvios, just one note on @Belmiris answer, who might confuse novices:
To retrieve the last inserted serial value, you don't need to specify the tabid in the SELECT DBINFO query. Just a

SELECT DBINFO( 'sqlca.sqlerrd1' ) FROM systables LIMIT 1 will sufice.